# Plotting ROC Curve with TPRate and FPRate in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two matrices with TPRate and FPRate. I want to plot an ROC Curve with that two matrices. I tried `plotroc` function of matlab but can't understand what its parameter. Is it like this?

```
plotroc(TPRate, FPRate)
```

If not how can I plot the ROC Curve with that two matrices?

Comment: plotroc looks specific to the  neural net toolbox and seems to expect inputs from neural net training and sim.

Comment: So how can I get the roc curve? I calculated the discriminant value with bayesian classifier of arbitrary covariance and found TPRate and FPRate for 10 fold cross validation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `perfcurve` ?

Check out the documentation - http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html - there are a couple of examples of the kind of ROC curve plots that you want (TPRate vs FPRate).